# firebase order by datetime desc and asc

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so i learn something new from firebase realtime for chat purpose..

but i still confuse how to make an action "how to order by like php"

so i have some code like this

```
var timenow=moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:m:s');
firebase.database().ref('message/notification').orderByChild("lastupdate").startAt(timenow).on('value',function(snapshot){
listuser.innerHTML+=snapshot.val().name;

});
```

here my database

[image]

How to order limit asc and desc method with lastupdate child? im search for reference that mostly tutorial for android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already retrieving the data ordered by their `lastupdate` and starting at "now". But your code for then handling the results is incorrect.

In the callback you'll want to loop over the results from the database with `forEach` and then add each individual node to the HTML. That'd look something like this:

```
firebase.database().ref('message/notification').orderByChild("lastupdate").startAt(timenow).on('value',function(snapshot){
  listuser.innerHTML = "";
  snapshot.forEach(function(notificationSnapshot) {
    listuser.innerHTML += notificationSnapshot.val().name;
  });
});
```

---

Alternatively, you can listen for the `child_added` event instead of `value`, which means that Firebase calls you for each individual child that is added. By listening to `child_added` and you won't need the loop in the callback:

```
firebase.database().ref('message/notification').orderByChild("lastupdate").startAt(timenow).on('child_added',function(snapshot){
  listuser.innerHTML += snapshot.val().name;
});
```

---

There is no way to retrieve your data from Firebase in descending order, so you'll have to reverse it in your application code. The simplest way to do that, is by changing how you add it to the HTML to always **prepend** the new data to the existing HTML:

```
listuser.innerHTML = snapshot.val().name + listuser.innerHTML;
```

---

Finally: there are many thousands of questions about Firebase already, so it really helps if you can tailor your search to what you need. For example: to find questions about the Realtime Database in JavaScript, I tend to [search for the combination of those tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-realtime-database+javascript). By adding more terms to the search, you can usually zoom in pretty well. For example: these are questions about [querying in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+%5Bjavascript%5D+query+descending).